# How to print out 'Live' mouse position coordinates using pyautogui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I used lots of different source codes, and even copied  and pasted but I keep getting random symbols that shift  when i move my mouse over them
here is my code...

```
import pyautogui, time, sys
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        CurserPos = pyautogui.position()
        print('\b' * len(CurserPos), end='\r')
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

I will show the output as an image. 
I am rather new to Python and would really appreciate some expert advice. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want printed out, but I don't think the first argument of the print function is what you want. `'\b' * len(CurserPos)` will "print" the backspace character ('\b') two times (note that CurserPos will always be 2 since `pyautogui.position()` always returns a tuple of two items).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Code :

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

Here is some output :

```
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
X:  0 Y: 1143 RGB: ( 38,  38,  38)
```

Here is the video where this is being demonstrated https://youtu.be/dZLyfbSQPXI?t=809

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH this really helps!

Comment: you are the savior

Answer (score 8):

This code will print the live position of your mouse after every one second.

```
import pyautogui as py #Import pyautogui
import time #Import Time

while True: #Start loop
    print (py.position())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Pyautogui can programmatically control the mouse & keyboard.

More information about it can be found here https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I use this while loop often but how can I only get a print if there is a click? I want to store the position of four click points as tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Use pyautogui.displayMousePosition() instead of pyautogui.position()

Answer (score 0):

If you want the coordinates of `displayMousePosition` stored in a variable, try this:

```py
import pyautogui

def getMousePosition():
    pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
    coords = pyautogui.position()
    return coords
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn´t like to be printing in the terminal the position of the mouse so I made a simple draggable GUI to display mouse location. Hope it helps:
https://github.com/Setibs/Mouse-position-GUI

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34821343)

Answer (score 0):

Also try this one:

```
import time as t
import mouseinfo
mouseinfo.MouseInfoWindow()
```

[Image of Mouse Window opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmQey.png)