# Selenium - How to get the mouse position

Tags: python, selenium

I've moved to a specific object position using `ActionChians` `move_to_element` function. Later on I use the `move_by_offset` function to move to a specific point of the page but the mouse position is set to the position of the element used in the `move_to_element` function. Now, the point in which I want to move to is fixed and everytime I need to move the mouse position to the (0, 0) point of the page using the `move_by_offset` function with (-position_X_of_last_element, -position_Y_of_last_element) and then move to the point in which I want to move. Since it is very annoying to track everytime the position of the element used in the `move_to_element` function, I was curious if it exists a method to retrieve the mouse position on the page

Comment: Try to check how you can get coordinates using javascript and than you can execute that javascript using `JavascriptExecutor` in selenium. You will be able to find related topics on stackoverlow itself.

Answer (score 0):

See this question and answer for a Python solution: [How to print out 'Live' mouse position coordinates using pyautogui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533241/how-to-print-out-live-mouse-position-coordinates-using-pyautogui)

Also view the linked YouTube video from about 13 minutes in.

Comment: Is this not possible with Selenium?

Comment: not sure - I have not personally used Selenium and it can be driven from different code languages, I have used pyautogui in python to create a mouse location reader as demonstrated in the linked answer and video