PyAutoGui on Debian repeats incorrect mouse position
I'm attempting to automate opening a website on a Raspberry Pi and then click a few buttons.
I tried making a quick script to get the current mouse position and then print it:
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    a = pyautogui.position()
    print(a)
    time.sleep(1)

However, when running this it outputs the same mouse position every time, over and over.
I then decided to try a different module, pymouse (now pyuserinput) which has very similar functions including PyMouse.position(). When trying this, is did the exact same and printed the same, incorrect mouse position.
I then tried moving the mouse and clicking it at a location to see if it worked. I moved the mouse to (10,10) but it didn't visually do anything however, now when I get the mouse position it says the mouse is at (10,10) even though it isn't.
From all the testing it seems like it is either an issue with how I'm running the script, or the OS.
Info:
Running this on a Raspberry Pi 4
PRETTY-NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"

I've looked here which seems to be the same issue however the answer isn't applicable for me and there's no other solutions recommended.

you may want to consider using something like selenium to automate doing things on a website. As for pyautogui are there different coordinates printed when you try to capture different pixels on your screen (manually) using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533241/how-to-print-out-live-mouse-position-coordinates-using-pyautogui or are they always the same coordinates? What are you doing to move the mouse to the coordinate that you require?

@AndrewRyan I did attempt to use Selenium however couldn't get it to work with the chromedriver. (Can't remember the specific error). I used pyautogui.position() to get the position within a loop, and every time it printed the same mouse position. I then used .move() and .click() to attempt moving/clicking the mouse on a specific spot (10,10) however this didn't move the cursor on the screen or click anything. But, when I then ran  .position() it then outputted (10,10) over and over.

when you run pyautogui.position() and move your mouse around -- do any of the values change? Have you tried going to various other positions (besides 10,10 to see if the mouse moves)
